# change default list indentation for all lists, word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word

i wanted to ask how to change the indentation for all lists (including multi-leveled) to indent one inch inward? for example if i have...

1. monster 
   a. color
2. human 
   a. color

i want a. to be indented one inch inward, and any other list nested under it to be indented as well. i can do it manually, by clicking on a. under monster and then adjusting the line indentation. however, it just affects that list. i have to do it again for the a. under human. how can i change every indentation to indent 1" regardless of what level it is nested under?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Click on the Multilevel List button on the Ribbon and choose Define New Multilevel List.

Then, increase the "aligned at" value by the amount you want to indent and increase the text indent level by the same amount.

Select "Set for all levels" and set the "additional indent for each level" to the value you want.

Press okay and then okay again.

You should be set.

(And welcome to Superuser!)

Comment: thank you! it took me a while to figure out haha. i didnt know that defining a list was specific to that level you were clicking on. but i understand what you mean now! it works! thank you!