# How to set default 'Adjust List Indents' - Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

I can achieve the following for Numbering each document separately, but http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/change-bullet-indents-HA102840162.aspx doesn't instruct how to 'defaultise' this.

I also tried http://shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html
and [change default list indentation for all lists, word 2010](https://superuser.com/q/541932/269574), but this latter is for Word 2010.

**Update on Oct 8 2014:** I read user DavidPostill's [recommendation](http://www.wordarticles.com/Articles/WordStyles/StylesPane.php) but still don't see the relevance? I add some screenshots below to illustrate:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Change it in the default styles?

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks, but how? I think you mean: Home > Styles > Select Any Style > Right Click: Modify? Then?

Comment: Read [Styles (Word 2007 and later)](http://www.wordarticles.com/Articles/WordStyles/StylesPane.php)

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks. This problem still plagues me. Would you please see my updated OP?

Comment: I don't have Word 2013 installed here so I can't guide you through it. Search for "word 2013 manage styles" and I'm sure you will figure it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are hints and bits in the comments already, but I'll try to put it together. If I understand correctly, you want to have some (list indent) settings in any new document instead of re-applying those settings every time you need them.

There are two steps to achieve this:

1. Apply the desired settings to a style
2. Save the style in the document template `normal.dotm`

**Apply the desired settings to a style**
Styles contain many layout settings. Every style had a name. This had the advantage that your document's layout is consistent and can be managed by editing the styles instead of all around your document. Say you have a bullet list named "Bullet list" and you want to change the style of that bullets from filled bullets to open bullets, you just change the style, and every occurrence of that bullet list in your document is changed. The basic idea behind all this is the separations of presentation (style) and content, which is widely adopted on web pages, where style (css) and content are also separated.

Now follow these steps to change the default behavior of numbered lists:

- Open a new document
- Create a numbered list and apply any formatting you like
- Select the numbered list you just created
- Click on the Styles drop-down in the Office ribbon and check which style is used. If it is a specific style for numbered lists (like the Office default "List Paragraph"), right-click on that style and select "Update  to match selection". If another style is selected, like "Normal", select "Save selection as a New Quick Style..." and give it a meaningful name.
- Finally, drop-down the Styles from the Ribbon again, and right-click on the style you just created. Click "Modify...". Make sure that the line "Style for following paragraph" has the value "List Paragraph". This makes sure that any new list is based on this style.

Now, any time you create a numbered list in *this* document, this style is applied. Cool, huh? But now you want to put this style in any new document that you create...

**Save the style in the document template `normal.dotm`**
Any new Word document is created from the template `normal.dotm`. To have your style in any new document, we have to put that style in your `normal.dotx`.  Follow these steps:

- In Word, close all documents.
- Click "File", "Open...", on the top left, select "Microsoft Word" and click "Templates". There you should see the `normal.dotm` file. Open it. If you can't find this file, browse to the following path: `C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates` and open it from there.
- Validate that you have this file actually opened, as the file name should appear in the title bar.
- Modify the style for numbered lists, just as you just did (this is hopefully the last time you have to do this...)
- Save the document.

Now, any new document (based on the normal template) should have your numbered list style in it. This style should be applied if you create a numbered list and/or if you apply your style to a any text in your document.

Note that the above approach works for all styles *and* content *and* any layout defined in the `normal.dotm` file. So you can change the default paragraph spacing, headers/footers, company logo, font, page numbers, etc.

Comment: +1. Thank you deeply. Would you please explain whether your answer only applies to the 'List Paragraph' style? I'd like the above to be set for the default 'Normal' template, so that I don't have to switch to 'List Paragraph' manually every time that I want to use a numbered list?

Comment: Thank you again. Can my preferences for NUmbered Lists be set for the default 'Normal' template, so that I don't have to switch to 'List Paragraph' manually every time that I want to use a numbered list? I realise that any document based on `normal.dotm` will feature the above.

Comment: If you use the default list style (ListParagraph is the style name I believe), Word should apply that style automatically if you create a list (by tying 1. <some text><enter> or by pushing the numbered list button in the ribbon).

Comment: Thanks again. I was just revisiting this and encountered two problems: 1. Was your answer meant to exist as two parts? The heading `Save the style in the document template ...` : Is this separate from the first heading? 2. `Click "File", "Open...", on the top left, select "Microsoft Word" and click "Templates".` : Is this right? I don't see the option for `Templates`.

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to user agtoever's answer, I thought to elucidate the 2nd bullet under **Save the style in the document template `normal.dotm`**
.

I could not find 'Templates' as directed. Instead, I first needed to go to Control Panel > Folder Options, to view all hidden folders. Then accordant with http://www.word-2013-tutorials.com/what-is-normal-dotm/, I had to open `normal.dotm` manually, in the same manner as opening another saved Word file. The key was to Open > Browse, and then type in `C:\Users\(username) (mine was 'admin')\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates`, when I then saw the desired file.

Comment: Added this suggestion (and the answer to your comment of my question) to my answer. If this is good enough for you, I suggest we'll delete our comments and this answer too (to keep things clean here on SU).